# Windows 7 Bootable usb BCDBOOT won't run

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I'm creating a windows 7 bootable usb drive.  I've already imaged my usb drive but I'm having trouble running my final command to copy the boot files over.  This is the command I'm running from an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdboot.exe E:\windows /s E: /f ALL
```

When I run this the BCD Help page shows as if I've entered an invalid option

[image]

I'm installing windows 7 on a usb drive, my current os is Windows 7 as well.
I'm pretty sure this will run but I don't want to do it with out that option in case it messes up my install:

```
bcdboot.exe E:\windows /s E:
```

I think the /f ALL options is not valid.

What is the /f all Option? and is it needed to get the USB drive operational?

Answer (score 1):

You should try in following order

bcdboot "SOURCE" /s "Target Drive": /f ALL

1.SOURCE is "e:\Windows" or if you are trying to copy from windows image file from your USB drive(Let say it is j) then it should be "j:\Windows"

2. s/ to create the partition as system partition immediately after this key you have to type the target drive that will be created as system partition
3. "t" the target drive that will be created as system partition
4. /f All for both BIOS and UEFI firmware. Keep in mind that /f without "All" won't work.